# i am getting NA in all the techniques to combine the two dataset using R(specifics mentioned _

Tags: r, join, dplyr

i am trying to combine two dataset `train` and `poptable`poptable with  the matching key is `"State.Name"`.

```
str(train)

'data.frame':   550242 obs. of  8 variables:

 $ State.Name       : chr  "ANDHRA PRADESH" "ANDHRA PRADESH" "ANDHRA   PRADESH" "ANDHRA PRADESH" ...
 $ District.Name    : chr  "EAST GODAVARI(04)" "EAST GODAVARI(04)" "EAST GODAVARI(04)" "EAST GODAVARI(04)" ...
 $ Block.Name       : chr  "PRATHIPADU(10)" "PRATHIPADU(10)" "PRATHIPADU(10)" "PRATHIPADU(10)" ...
 $ Panchayat.Name   : chr  "GOKAVARAM(04)" "GOKAVARAM(04)" "GAJJANAPUDI(06)" "GAJJANAPUDI(06)" ...
 $ Village.Name     : chr  "VANTHADA(014 )" "PANDAVULAPALEM(022 )" "G. KOTHURU(023 )" "GAJJANAPUDI(029 )" ...
 $ Habitation.Name  : chr  "VANTHADA(0404410014010400)" "PANDAVULAPALEM(0404410022010400)" "G. KOTHURU(0404410023010600)" "GAJJANAPUDI(0404410029010600)" ...
 $ Quality.Parameter: chr  "Salinity" "Fluoride" "Salinity" "Salinity" ...
 $ Year             : Date, format: "2009-04-01" "2009-04-01" "2009-04-01" ...
```

and second data set

```
str(poptable)

'data.frame':   33 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ State.Name: chr  "ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR    " "ANDHRA PRADESH     " "ARUNACHAL PRADESH    " "ASSAM    " ...
 $ latitude  : num  11.7 14.8 27.1 26.7 25.8 ...
 $ longitude : num  92.7 78.6 93.6 94.2 87.5 ...
```

i tried using dplyr and join the datasets using  inner join. 
       `train <- inner_join(train,poptable,by="State.Name")`

```
str(train)
 'data.frame':  0 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ State.Name       : chr 
 $ District.Name    : chr 
 $ Block.Name       : chr 
 $ Panchayat.Name   : chr 
 $ Village.Name     : chr 
 $ Habitation.Name  : chr 
 $ Quality.Parameter: chr 
 $ Year             :Class 'Date'  num(0) 
 $ latitude         : num 
 $ longitude        : num
```

i then tried using full_join.still getting NA ,data_type is numeric.

```
train <- full_join(train,poptable,by="State.Name")




str(train)
'data.frame':   550275 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ State.Name       : chr  "ANDHRA PRADESH" "ANDHRA PRADESH" "ANDHRA PRADESH" "ANDHRA PRADESH" ...
 $ District.Name    : chr  "EAST GODAVARI(04)" "EAST GODAVARI(04)" "EAST GODAVARI(04)" "EAST GODAVARI(04)" ...
 $ Block.Name       : chr  "PRATHIPADU(10)" "PRATHIPADU(10)" "PRATHIPADU(10)" "PRATHIPADU(10)" ...
 $ Panchayat.Name   : chr  "GOKAVARAM(04)" "GOKAVARAM(04)" "GAJJANAPUDI(06)" "GAJJANAPUDI(06)" ...
 $ Village.Name     : chr  "VANTHADA(014 )" "PANDAVULAPALEM(022 )" "G. KOTHURU(023 )" "GAJJANAPUDI(029 )" ...
 $ Habitation.Name  : chr  "VANTHADA(0404410014010400)" "PANDAVULAPALEM(0404410022010400)" "G. KOTHURU(0404410023010600)" "GAJJANAPUDI(0404410029010600)" ...
 $ Quality.Parameter: chr  "Salinity" "Fluoride" "Salinity" "Salinity" ...
 $ Year             : Date, format: "2009-04-01" "2009-04-01" "2009-04-01" ...
 $ latitude         : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ longitude        : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...`
```

i even tried to use match function i am still getting NA is the latitude column.

`train$latitude<- poptable$latitude[match(train$State.Name,poptable$State.Name)]`

```
str(train)
'data.frame':   550242 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ State.Name       : chr  "ANDHRA PRADESH" "ANDHRA PRADESH" "ANDHRA PRADESH" "ANDHRA PRADESH" ...
 $ District.Name    : chr  "EAST GODAVARI(04)" "EAST GODAVARI(04)" "EAST GODAVARI(04)" "EAST GODAVARI(04)" ...
 $ Block.Name       : chr  "PRATHIPADU(10)" "PRATHIPADU(10)" "PRATHIPADU(10)" "PRATHIPADU(10)" ...
 $ Panchayat.Name   : chr  "GOKAVARAM(04)" "GOKAVARAM(04)" "GAJJANAPUDI(06)" "GAJJANAPUDI(06)" ...
 $ Village.Name     : chr  "VANTHADA(014 )" "PANDAVULAPALEM(022 )" "G. KOTHURU(023 )" "GAJJANAPUDI(029 )" ...
 $ Habitation.Name  : chr  "VANTHADA(0404410014010400)" "PANDAVULAPALEM(0404410022010400)" "G. KOTHURU(0404410023010600)" "GAJJANAPUDI(0404410029010600)" ...
 $ Quality.Parameter: chr  "Salinity" "Fluoride" "Salinity" "Salinity" ...
 $ Year             : Date, format: "2009-04-01" "2009-04-01" "2009-04-01" ...
 $ latitude         : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

**still not getting the idea why the numeric data is not being transsfered to the `train` by matching first column `"State.Name"`**

Comment: Your `poptable` has white space in `State.Name`. So they have no values in common. You can fix that with `timws`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to run any kind of match, the values in the shared column must have exactly the same names. It looks like your state names are written in slightly different ways. For example, `"ANDHRA PRADESH     "` is followed by five spaces and will only match other values that are trailed by five spaces. It will not match `ANDHRA   PRADESH` or `ANDRA`, which is what you're trying to match it against in the other dataset.

Try running `table(train$State.Name)` and compare it to `table(poptable$State.Name)`. Look for any state names that should be the same but aren't.

Comment: yes the reason was the white spaces **thank you** i used a user defined function to trim the leading and trailing spaces     `trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)`

Comment: I'm glad that fixed your problem! This is the first time I've ever seen a downvoted answer selected as the preferred response :-)

Comment: i didn't downvoted it.The logic was right,as i am new to R, i couldn't identify the white spaces just seeing the console,thought something wrong with my code.The answer gave me direction then i search again in this beautiful community and wola!!.

Comment: I know you didn't downvote it, didn't mean to make it sound otherwise. I just found it amusing. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do that column by column join.

For example

```
full_join(train, poptable, by = c("State.Name" = "State.Name"))
```

Comment: may it because of your data. all data is same lowercase or uppercase ?

Comment: i have converted all the characters to upper cases its not that i guess.

Comment: It was beacuse of the white spaces. I used a user defined function to trim the leading and trailing spaces `trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)`